# single file LaTeX

Tags: editors

I started teaching LaTeX to my colleagues and in the introduction, I showed them that a `docx` file can be unzipped, and it also contains marked up plain text files. This got me thinking: one of the things I am not exactly thrilled with in LaTeX is that it creates a ton of files, so in practice, if I have many documents I need to create separate folders for them, but then you need to step into them to get the pdf etc. Wouldn't it be possible to write a LaTeX editor, which can store everything in a zip, run LaTeX there, handle the files inside etc, and possible drop the pdf beside the zip, when done? Is there something like this?

Comment: Are you talking about the auxiliary files? Those are not necessary and can be deleted. TeXstudio provides a GUI just for that purpose.

Comment: Well, to be honest, the auxiliary files are a pain **** as well (although deleting them manually is just that one more thing you need to do), but normally you have separate folder for the figures, your bib file(s), usually several other files. Kind of a mess, really.

Comment: there is really very little difference in practice between a zip archive and a filesystem they are just low level filesystem encodings, some filesystems already let you transparently use a zippped directory as a directory, but how do you gain from using a directory and then zipping it if you need to transport it, instead of using a zip file and having the system repeatedly zip and unzip it in the background on every operation?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My point is not transportation. It's compactness. I don't have a multiple folder structure hanging around for my docx and odt files. They do not clutter. Obviously, you make a point about the zip overhead. I'm pretty sure it can be made negligable compared to building the pdf, but a valid point nontheless.

Comment: clutter only matters if you look, the directory that I use for testing answers on this site appears to have 1245 aux files at the moment (and I do clean it up every now and then:-)

Comment: There was a project by Jerôme Laurens (the author of SyncTeX) for a TeX front-end on Mac OS X, where a whole project would appear as a single file (actually a directory). Nice idea, but not developed.

Comment: You stated: "[don't like] that it creates a ton of files [...]", so I thought of generated files. However, in your comment you name content by the writer (which I personally like to have control about, instead of embedding in dubious files), therefore maybe have a look at [filecontent](https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents?lang=en). As far as I know, it will create all files specified, but then again those could be deleted like auxiliaries.

Answer (score 2):

Preliminary answers to both your questions: It would and there isn't.

Comment: Well, that's to the point :D

Comment: As David Carlisle suggested in his comment, I suppose one could get this behavior with a script that handles the zipping.

Comment: As egreg said: there were plans . . .

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, `pandoc` does this too.

Although I personally use `pandoc` to convert markdown to LaTeX and then take the usual course of action myself, it is possible to use `pandoc` to convert LaTeX source to PDF. I observed no auxiliary files after such compilation, and internally, still LaTeX is used.

You might want to use an additional *template* file for styling and switch your colleagues directly to markdown.

Answer (score 1):

With the exception that latex will not be run in a zip, but in a normal folder, this sounds like a good job for ltx2any. It's a LaTeX build wrapper that runs latex in a folder of your choice

sample call:

```
ltx2any -t path_where_you_want_the_auxiliary_files_to_go filename.tex
```